# How to parse HTL content

Tags: aem, sightly

I'm loading a resource in [AEM](https://helpx.adobe.com/support/experience-manager.html) using [`SlingRequestProcessor`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling10/org/apache/sling/engine/SlingRequestProcessor.html) as the example available [here](https://gist.github.com/nateyolles/1dc9f8699fce70916764).

My page/html file looks like:

```
<div data-sly-use.stepPlanItem="stepPlanItemTemplate.html"
    data-sly-call="${stepPlanItem.step @ step = step}"
    data-sly-unwrap />
```

But, when I invoke `requestProcessor.processRequest(req, resp, request.getResourceResolver());` nothing happens. I'm getting exactly the same content of the file. Nothing is being parsed.

My main question is: **How can I parse sly tags from Java code?**

Should I use filters? Which one? This is a page (not an AEM one) just an HTL snippet.

Comment: Are you trying to render a file such as `/content/myapp/myfile.html` with this content and expecting HTL to be parsed and executed? You need to check how Sling Resource Resolution works first: https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/sling-cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to parse HTL files, this is done by the Sling Scripting Engine implementation. You are always processing/loading a resource and it needs to be resolved according to the [Sling resource resolution](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/sling-cheatsheet.html).

Assuming you are trying to load a resource at: `/content/myapp/mypage.html` that has a `sling:resourceType=myapp/myfile`, you would put the above code snippet in an `/apps/myapp/myfile/myfile.html` file so that the scripting engine can execute the HTL.